# PowerShell Set-AzureADApplication permissions

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, service-principal

I’ve been trying for a while to develop a PowerShell script that will allow us to add reply urls to an Ad app. The script runs fine until it gets to the part where the app needs to be updated “Set-AzureADApplication” gets called. I keep getting an Insufficient privileges error. Does anyone know what privileges I need to get the app running?[image]

Comment: Please DON'T show an image of error messages, but insert it in the question as (formatted) text.

Comment: It would also be useful to show the command being used  and if you need least privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD Permissions for managing applications can be granted with multiple roles, from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles

**Application Administrator:** Users in this role can create and manage all aspects of enterprise applications, application registrations, and application proxy settings.

**Application Developer:** Users in this role can create application registrations when the "Users can register applications" setting is set to No.

**Global Administrator / Company Administrator:** Users with this role have access to all administrative features in Azure Active Directory...

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to **Powershell execution policy**.

You can run this PS command before executing your code:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process -Force
```